# Adding realtime listeners on firestore subcollections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to have realtime listener on a subcollection in firestore? I have a subcollection called meetings and when I add a new document the listener is not triggered. Below is a sample of my code.
any idea on what should I do? I know I can use top level collection for meetings but in my case I want things to be subcollections way in some parts.

```
export const getMeetings = (projectId) => {
  const meetingsCollection = firestore.collection('projects-meetings')
  return (dispatch) => {
    meetingsCollection.doc(projectId).collection('meetings').onSnapshot((querySnapShot) => {
      const array = [];
      querySnapShot.forEach(doc => {
        const meeting = { ...doc.data() }
        array.push(meeting)
      })
      dispatch({ type: meetingsActions.GET_MEETINGS_SUCCESS, payload: array });
    }, (err => {
      dispatch({ type: meetingsActions.GET_MEETINGS_ERROR }, err);
    })
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Realtime listeners work the same on subcollections as they do on top-level collections. If your code doesn't work, it isn't because subcollections are different. Did you already put a breakpoint on `const array = [];` and see if it ever reaches there when run in a debugger?

Comment: Just to clarify: your listener will be triggered on any change in the `meetings` under `meetingsCollection.doc(projectId)`. The `meetingsCollection` variable looks a bit suspicious though, as I'd expect that to be `projectsCollection` or something like that.

Comment: the code does not reach there when the sub-collection is updated. I am using calling the function in the question in my component's componentDidMount

Comment: I edited my question to add the meetingsCollection

Answer (score 1):

So figured it out. The problem was with using Redux-Persist. I don't know why but it was not fetching data when things were changing in firestore. when I disabled redux persist it worked fine. But I really want to use redux-persist and I don't know if it is necessary with Firebase local persistence enabled.